# .Net Assembly loading error: "cannot find the file specified"

Tags: c#, .net, load, .net-assembly

I got run time error as follows:

> Could not load file or assembly 'ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.
>   ":"ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var path = @"D:\Temp\ClassLibrary1.dll";

    AppDomain other = AppDomain.CreateDomain("other");
    Type myType = typeof(AssemblyLoader);           
    AssemblyLoader loader = (AssemblyLoader)other.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(myType.Assembly.FullName, myType.FullName);

    loader.LoadAssembly(path);
    string[] types = loader.GetTypeNames();

    var ts = loader.GetTypes();

}
```

AssemblyLoader is like

```
public class AssemblyLoader:MarshalByRefObject
{
    private Assembly assembly;
    private string assemblyName;
    public AssemblyLoader()
    {          
    }      
    public void LoadAssembly(string path)
    {          
        assembly = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
        assemblyName = assembly.FullName;         
    }
    public Type[] GetTypes()
    {
        var types = assembly.GetExportedTypes();
        List<object> objs = new List<object>();
        types.ToList().ForEach(s => objs.Add(CreateInstance(s.Name)));
        return objs.Select(s => s.GetType()).ToArray();
    }
    public string[] GetTypeNames()
    {           
        return Array.ConvertAll<Type, string>(assembly.GetExportedTypes(), x => x.FullName);
    }
   public  object CreateInstance(string typeName)
    {           
        return Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, typeName).Unwrap();           

    }
    public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you reinvent the wheel? what is wrong with Assembly.Load method

Comment: @EmrahSüngü I need an instance to get properties of the type. That's why I need to create instance of the type. I got error when I create instance.